# How to see the changes between two commits without commits in-between using java?

Tags: java, jgit

I want to find out the differences between two commits using java,
can somebody help me?

Comment: The question sounds both a bit too broad and a bit vague. What did you try already? What do you mean with "without commits in-between"? Please share code, errors or other information that you found already.

Comment: I try compare to commit how I can do that using java, JGit?

Answer (score 0):

With [git24j](https://github.com/git24j/git24j) , you can do:

```
Tree t1 = (Tree) Tree.lookup(repo, Oid.of(TREE_SHA1), GitObject.Type.TREE);
Tree t2 = (Tree) Tree.lookup(repo, Oid.of(TREE_SHA2), GitObject.Type.TREE); 
Diff diff = Diff.treeToTree(repo, t1, t2, Diff.Options.create(Diff.Options.CURRENT_VERSION));
// once you get the diff object, you can access Diff.Delta
Diff.Delta delta = diff.getDelta(0);
// or iterate over all deltas:
diff.foreach(<callbacks>)
```

Note: the code calculates tree diffs because a git commit is actually a snapshot of the working tree. When you say you want to diff two commits, you actually want to diff two trees.